# script is not working with routerLink in Angular 2/4

Tags: jquery, angular, materialize

I'm using Materialize CSS in my Angular app and the scrip initialization doesn't work with routerLink

```
<a routerLink="" />
```

It's just working when i use a href link - normal link.

```
<a href="" />
```

How can i resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

What from Materialize doesn't work? You just mention *scrip initialization*, but I'm not sure what you mean.

I will add though that the use of `href` will essentially refresh the "refresh" the page as it will request resources from the server, where as the `routerLink` will only tell the Angular app to navigate inside of the application. I'm assuming the issue comes from the fact that when navigating to a new route Materialize has already ran its code, and the newly created components do not have the JQuery applied to them.

With that in mind I would advise you looking at the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook as you will need to manually initialize the JQuery plugins. In fact a lot of the JavaScript driven bits on the Materialize documentation have a *jQuery Plugin Initialization* section where you can put that code into your AfterViewInit lifecycle hook.